# Java, problem with accessing class methods

Tags: java, retrofit2

Problem accesing methods from class instances, I use `Retrofit 2` for api response, and seems it is something wrong with my pojo files structure.

When I use  pojo classes for example: `Service` and `ServiceData` which have methods Service: getData, ServiceData: getId i can their access methods in order Service service = response.body(); service.getData.getId everythin works fine, but when response have to be List and than i cant access getId method. I cant change API response, only deal with it in code.

problem code

```
public void onResponse(Call<ServicesInGroup> call, Response<ServicesInGroup> response) {
    ServicesInGroup post = response.body();
    if (post != null) {
        String data = post.getData().has to be getService_id() but there is not
```

pojo class ServicesInGroup

```
public class ServicesInGroup {

    @SerializedName("result")
    private String result;

    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<ServicesInGroupData> data;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public List<ServicesInGroupData> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<ServicesInGroupData> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

pojo class ServicesInGroupData

```
public class ServicesInGroupData {

    @SerializedName("service_id")
    private String service_id;

    @SerializedName("provider_id")
    private String provider_id;

    public String getService_id ()
    {
        return service_id;
    }

    public void setService_id (String service_id)
    {
        this.service_id = service_id;
    }

    public String getProvider_id ()
    {
        return provider_id;
    }

    public void setProvider_id (String provider_id)
    {
        this.provider_id = provider_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont know about retrofit, but my guess is, its because list is not initialized

Comment: post.getData() is List, you have to iterate the list to get all ids or either use index to get specific id.

Comment: I used index to get them, thank you